# Call of Duty Black Ops Perks

Tags: nintendo-wii, call-of-duty-black-ops

I'm playing the Wii version of Call of Duty: Black Ops.  Of the perks available, I'm thinking of going for the stealth perks, but was wondering which perks combined together do you think is the ultimate combination?

Comment: You need to specify a purpose of the class if you want tips on perk selection. There is no one magic combination to go with.

Comment: Reopen to close again for needing more details and clarity. At this point this question needs to be closed anyway, because 'ultimate' in this context *is* opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tier 1: Ghost

Tier 2: Sleight of Hand or Warlord.  You need to attach a suppressor to your weapon

Tier 3: Ninja or Hacker.  For a true stealth class, Ninja would be the way to go but Hacker is a good choice to sniff out those pesky claymores.

For your lethal, I would use the Tomahawk for silent kills.  For your equipment, I would use the motion sensor to detect anyone that is near by.

Comment: If you have a headset or use earphones having ninja is god like. You never hear your own footsteps but hear reloads and foot steps of enemies and sadly all allies not wearing Ninja pro.

Answer (score 0):

If you want stealth:
1) Ghost
2) Sleight of Hand (use supressor, its better to get used to the iron sight)
3) Ninja

I always use Semtex in every custom class, and for equipment I preffer Stun Grenades (you can throw them really fast) or Decoy.

Try using a SMG with:
1) Lightweight
2) Sleight of Hand
3) Maraton

Semtex

Answer (score 0):

Stealth but requires a good aim because you cant afford to waste ammo: ghost pro, sleight of hand pro, and hacker pro

Offense: Scavenger pro, sleight of hand pro, and hacker pro
 So far this worked with me great, don't forget to use a suppressed weapon in stealth otherwise it beats the whole purpose, as for offense I suggest using assault rifles with sights like the commando or famas with red dot or an M60 if you want to go crazy and keep holding the trigger. Have fun.

Answer (score -1):

you are definitely going to need **scavenger pro** and **hacker pro** i don't know but the last one is **up to your preference**. For scavenger pro it takes away the need to conserve bullets and Hacker pro could help if your team is loosing and the other team has advantages like care packages and other things

Comment: You are grave digging ;)

Comment: Can you expand on this? Why do you think those perks are useful in this context?

Comment: For scavenger pro it takes away the need to conserve bullets and Hacker pro could help if your team is loosing and the other team has advantages like care packages and other things.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen There's no rule against that here...as long as the answer is good and the question is worth answering, at least.